# convert HttpWebRequest authentication with cookies into UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cookies, httpwebrequest, unitywebrequest

I'm authenticating with a server that, through a series of redirects sets a CSRF cookie. I also get a oauth2 cookie that I need to include for all subsequent queries.

I'm able to obtain all the cookies and authenticate using `HttpWebRequest` - but I'd like to convert this to use `UnityWebRequest` so I can make use of Coroutines to not block the main game loop.

I am able to obtain the CSRF cookie in both `HttpWebRequest` and `UnityWebRequest` - ✅

The issue I'm having is how to send this CSRF cookie using `UnityWebRequest` when trying to login.

My `HttpWebRequest` looks like this...

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TrustCertificate;
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 request.KeepAlive = true;
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.Method = method;
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
 request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 Cookie csrf = new Cookie("_oauth2_proxy_csrf", CSRF_COOKIE, "/", server_ip);
 request.CookieContainer.Add(csrf);
 request.Proxy = null;
 
 if (method == "POST")
 {
     NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
     nvc.Add("login", username);
     nvc.Add("password", password);
     StringBuilder postVars = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (string key in nvc)
         postVars.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", key, nvc[key]);
     postVars.Length -= 1; // clip off the remaining &
 
     using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
     {
         streamWriter.Write(postVars.ToString());
     }
 }
 
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This works successfully, the server authenticates me and provides an authentication cookie - ✅

Now, my translated `UnityWebRequest` code looks like this...

```
 List<IMultipartFormSection> post_data = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
 post_data.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("login", username));
 post_data.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("password", password));
 
 UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, post_data);
 request.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.certificateHandler = new ForceAcceptAll();
 request.redirectLimit = 1;
 request.SetRequestHeader("_oauth2_proxy_csrf", CSRF_COOKIE);
 string cookie = string.Format("{0}={1}", "_oauth2_proxy_csrf", CSRF_COOKIE);
 request.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
 yield return request.SendWebRequest();
```

The server doesn't appear to be receiving the cookie correctly. It won't authenticate correctly and doesn't provide the auth cookie like it does with `HttpWebResponse`

I think it boils down to how to translate
`request.CookieContainer.Add(csrf);` into `UnityWebRequest` - ❓
which I thought would be:

```
string cookie = string.Format("{0}={1}", "_oauth2_proxy_csrf", CSRF_COOKIE);
request.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
```

The Unity docs say that `UnityWebRequest` has an internal [cookie engine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html) - but as far as I can see it completely opaque so I can't see what the contents are.

Comment: It looks like you aren’t setting a session value. 

Only oauth I’ve used I just needed to set token to a value not cookies

Comment: I tried setting it using `request.SetRequestHeader("_oauth2_proxy_csrf", CSRF_COOKIE);` 
- if this is what you mean?

Comment: No. Likely there are other headers. Such as session. And the oauth I used required a header of a token

Comment: @YMDW are able to fix this. Seems I have similar issue